# RTSP streaming not working in Nokia series 40 mobile phones

Tags: youtube, nokia, rtsp, series-40, live-video

I am new to creating Nokia application for the series 40 mobiles.

I am trying use YouTube channel videos for my application, but I am getting an error on the simulator:

`"The RTSP streaming feature is currently not supported in the Web Apps Simulator. Please test the streaming feature on one of the supported devices."`

I tested on supported devices using the Nokia deploy method, but it is still not working so please can anyone help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe on Nokia S40 series phones, live video streaming is not possible. May be due to some technical limitations [or say design limitations].

But when you open a web link which streams videos, [Some times and some devices] it gets opened in your media player and gets started to stream. But due to low quality antennas used for internet in the S40 series [Obviously entry level phones] internet speed will be less and it seems like video buffering or video streaming is not possible.

May be the device's simulator which you are using does not supports live video streaming. If you are internet connection is proper [and speedy as well] then this is the root cause.